# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol XYZFragment_

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I'm having a really hard time here trying to get someone's else's code to run (for maintenance purposes).

In several points of the code there's reference to a certain *XYZFragment_* class (XYZ standing for its real name). But I can't find this class anywhere (or generate it).

There is an *XYZFragment*, but it also references *XYZFragment_* at some point and tries to import it.

```
import com.example.XYZFragment;
import com.example.XYZFragment_;

XYZFragment fragment = new XYZFragment_();
```

What I am missing here? The project won't compile because it can't find this class.

I'm trying to build the project in Android Studio 0.4.0 with Android API 17. The module does have annotations enabled and I've setup the preprocessor and FQ name.

---

**EDIT:** Turns out I had to **Build > Rebuild Project** and *then* **Build > Make Project** in order to make it work, instead of only Build > Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 1):

This project seems to use [AndroidAnnotation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) framewok. Did you try to configure your environment to enable annotation processing (which should generate the missing classes). See the wiki pages about [project configuration](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: Yes, I did enable annotation processing and had the FQ name setup correctly. Turns out it was some weird Android Studio behavior when rebuilding. I had to Build > Rebuild Project and then Build > Make Project in order to make it work, instead of only Build > Rebuild Project or Build > Make Project.

Comment: Weird.. I should dig on this issue. Thanks for your feedback